# Resuming Batch File after UAC Prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a simple script which is just used run a list of executables.
So it just looks like

```
PATH\a.exe
PATH\b.exe
```

etc.

Problem is one of the executables needs to be run as as admin, so I have that one set to always run as admin. When the script gets to that particular exe the UAC prompt shows up, which is fine. But the script stops executing after I accept the prompt. How do I have the script continue executing afterwards?

Comment: Use the start command.

Comment: Run the CMD Script itself in an elevated command prompt.